# Noob but tricky for Excel experts:about counting cell with condition: if two paird cell is not empty.

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

had some problem
well i have a problem in excel
i want to count row if a criteria is met.
that criteria is to have both pair of cell is not empty for example

```
|foo    |       |
|foo    |bar    | //- here
|       |bar    |
|foo    |bar    | //- here
|foo    |       |
|foo    |bar    | //- here
```

in this example i have two columns with 6 rows.

and i want to count cell that the both columns is not empty.

so the answer is 3

ive tried to use countif but it seems i cant make it like that.

anyone?

Comment: Have you consider UDF??? (VBA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could also have used:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A25,"<>"&"",B1:B25,"<>"&"")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$25<>"")*--($B$1:$B$25<>""))` for compatibility with Excel 2003.

Answer (score -1):

In a few search, I found a useful formula.

```
=counta(a1:a25)-COUNTIFS(a1:a25,"",b1:b25,"")
```

`counta` will give me the total count of my rows.

Then countifs will count the empty cells paired with two columns (so like having an "`and`" operator)

Then subtracting them will give me the total number of non-empty paired columns.